# How to repeat the table column header in each page

Tags: php, mysql, fpdf

I'm using FPDF to create a PDF file which the data is getting pulled from a MySQL database. And the table is getting created with two main column headers "User Name" and "Total Time Spent".

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: SiNUX
 * Date: 8/3/2017
 * Time: 2:44 PM
 */

require('../Libraries/fpdf/fpdf.php');
include_once ('../iConnect/handShake.php');

class h4PDF extends FPDF{
    function Header(){
        $this->Image('../../images/logo.png', 10,6,30);
        $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
        $this->Cell(80);
        $this->Cell(50, 10, 'Total Spent Time', 0, 0,'C');
        $this->Ln(10);
    }
}

$getTot = "SELECT userlogin.uName, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(timeSpent))) AS totTime FROM usertimetrack
           LEFT JOIN userlogin ON usertimetrack.usrId = userlogin.uId WHERE jDate = :jdate GROUP BY usrId";
$getTotQuery = $dbConnect -> prepare($getTot);
$getTotQuery -> bindParam('jdate', $_REQUEST["date"]);
$getTotQuery -> execute();

$pdf = new h4PDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','', 14);
$pdf->SetFillColor(255,0,0);
$pdf->SetTextColor(255);
$pdf->SetDrawColor(128,0,0);
$pdf->SetLineWidth(.3);
$pdf->SetFont('','B');

$pdf->SetX(70);
$pdf->Cell(40,6,'User Name',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->SetX(105);
$pdf->SetX(110);
$pdf->Cell(42,6,'Total Spent Time',1,0,'C',1);
$pdf->Ln();

$pdf->SetFillColor(224,235,255);
$pdf->SetTextColor(0);
$pdf->SetFont('');

$fill = false;
while ($getTotRow = $getTotQuery -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $uName = $getTotRow["uName"];
    $totTime = $getTotRow["totTime"];

    $pdf->SetX(70);
    $pdf->Cell(40,6,$uName,'LR',0,'C',$fill);
    $pdf->SetX(105);
    $pdf->SetX(110);
    $pdf->Cell(42,6,$totTime ,'LR',0,'C',$fill);
    $pdf->Ln();
    $fill = !$fill;
}
$pdf->SetX(70);
$pdf->Cell(82,0,'','T');

$pdf->Output();
```

With the current code I can create the table but this code only prints the header of the table columns on the first page only actually at the beginning of the table and the rest will be filled with data which continues till the data ends. I wish to repeat these 2 header on each page at the beginning of the table on each page.

I tried to do something like [this](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script30.php) script but ended up creating an infinity loop.

I think I do have to do a manual data amount for the page, then turn off the auto page break, then check for the max data and then print the header if the table has reached it's max data amount. But I don't know how to plug that in to this code.

Can some one please show me how to do this, I'm posting this after many attempts which failed or ended up me breaking the entire script.

**UPDATE:**Thanks to kastriotcunaku I managed to solve my problem now my new code is as follows,

```
<?php
/**
 * Created by PhpStorm.
 * User: SiNUX
 * Date: 8/3/2017
 * Time: 2:44 PM
 */

require('../Libraries/fpdf/fpdf.php');
include_once ('../iConnect/handShake.php');

class h4PDF extends FPDF{
    function Header(){
        $this->Image('../../images/logo.png', 10,6,30);
        $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
        $this->Cell(80);
        $this->Cell(50, 10, 'Total Spent Time', 0, 0,'C');
        $this->Ln(10);

        $this->SetFont('Arial','', 14);
        $this->SetFillColor(255,0,0);
        $this->SetTextColor(255);
        $this->SetDrawColor(128,0,0);
        $this->SetX(74);
        $this->Cell(40,6,'User Name',1,0,'C',1);
        $this->SetX(109);
        $this->SetX(114);
        $this->Cell(42,6,'Total Spent Time',1,0,'C',1);
        $this->Ln();
    }
}

$getTot = "SELECT userlogin.uName, SEC_TO_TIME(SUM(TIME_TO_SEC(timeSpent))) AS totTime FROM usertimetrack
           LEFT JOIN userlogin ON usertimetrack.usrId = userlogin.uId WHERE jDate = :jdate GROUP BY usrId";
$getTotQuery = $dbConnect -> prepare($getTot);
$getTotQuery -> bindParam('jdate', $_REQUEST["date"]);
$getTotQuery -> execute();

$pdf = new h4PDF();
$pdf->AddPage();

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','', 14);
$pdf->SetFillColor(255,0,0);
$pdf->SetTextColor(255);
$pdf->SetDrawColor(128,0,0);
$pdf->SetLineWidth(.1);
$pdf->SetFont('','B');

$pdf->SetFillColor(224,235,255);
$pdf->SetTextColor(0);
$pdf->SetFont('');

$fill = false;
while ($getTotRow = $getTotQuery -> fetch(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC)){
    $uName = $getTotRow["jDate"];
    $totTime = $getTotRow["timeSpent"];

    $pdf->SetX(74);
    $pdf->Cell(40,6,$uName,'1',0,'C',$fill);
    $pdf->SetX(109);
    $pdf->SetX(114);
    $pdf->Cell(42,6,$totTime ,'1',0,'C',$fill);
    $pdf->Ln();
    $fill = !$fill;
}

$pdf->Output();
```

I removed the last line which was to be drawn after the while loop stops which actually was just leaving the end of the table with out a last line so I removed that and enable the borders of the cells and set the line width to 0.1 which made my table look much better.

Comment: Good question.  You can use the class [here](http://www.fpdf.org/en/script/script14.php)  to do what you want.

Comment: @gview I did try that it was built with older SQL I'm using PDO and my head almost exploded trying to convert that.

Comment: Yes, I see that could be an exercise.  Perhaps just convert it to mysqli, which would essentially be much simpler.  A bummer to have to use PDO and mysqli, but the mysqli_ library is going to be available regardless, to provide the support for PDO/mysql

Comment: I will be trying to convert that in future though so it will help more people.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need to specify table header inside function Header(), before $pdf->AddPage();

Try something like this:

```html
<?php

class h4PDF extends FPDF{
    function Header(){
        $this->Image('../../images/logo.png', 10,6,30);
        $this->SetFont('Arial', 'B', 12);
        $this->Cell(80);
        $this->Cell(50, 10, 'Total Spent Time', 0, 0,'C');
        $this->Ln(10);
        
        $this->SetX(70);
        $this->Cell(40,6,'User Name',1,0,'C',1);
        $this->SetX(105);
        $this->SetX(110);
        $this->Cell(42,6,'Total Spent Time',1,0,'C',1);
        $this->Ln();
    }
}

?>
```

Comment: I tried your suggestion and it did work now I have another problem the while loop doesn't close the last cell with a bottom border. This only get added when the loop stops. I did add the closing border to while which created a bottom border for all the cells.