# fpdf add title and table header on each page

Tags: php, pdf

```
<?Php
require('fpdf/fpdf.php');
$host = "localhost"; 
$username = "root"; 
$password = "";  
$db_name = "Students"; 

$con = new mysqli($host, $username, $password, $db_name);

$count = "SELECT * FROM class";

$pdf = new FPDF(); 
$pdf->AddPage();

$width_cell=array(70,40,30,30,20);
$pdf->SetFont('Arial','B',12);

$pdf->SetFillColor(193,229,252);

$pdf->Cell($width_cell[0],10,'ID No',1,0,'C',true);
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[1],10,'Name',1,0,'C',true);
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[2],10,'Surname',1,0,'C',true); 
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[3],10,'Cell No',1,0,'C',true);
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[4],10,'Teacher',1,1,'C',true); 

$pdf->SetFont('Arial','',11);
$pdf->SetFillColor(235,236,236); 
$fill=false;


foreach ($con->query($count) as $row) {
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[0],10,$row['Id_no'],1,0,'C',$fill);
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[1],10,$row['Name'],1,0,'C',$fill);
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[2],10,$row['Surname'],1,0,'C',$fill);
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[3],10,$row['CellNO'],1,0,'C',$fill);
$pdf->Cell($width_cell[4],10,$row['Teacher'],1,1,'C',$fill);
$fill = !$fill;
}

$pdf->Output();
?>
```

**Question**:How do i put in a title at the top of my page for each page. and the table header on each page. Been struggling and i tried the `fpdf` tutorial page on the website. But i still can't get it to work

Comment: you have to print specific count of row(tr) on each page i.e suppose your page allow 10 lines then echo title print 10 lines & on next page again print title & print next 10 rows

Comment: @Ash `echo` does not build into the pdf builder

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45561222/how-to-repeat-the-table-column-header-in-each-page

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe that you should extend the Fpdf class and work out a complete header section and footer section which will overwrite the default Header and Footer. See the following example.

```
class PDF extends FPDF
{
// Page header
function Header()
{

    $this->SetFillColor(54,80,104);
    $this->SetDrawColor(150,150,150);
    $this->Rect(0,0,220,50,'F');

    $this->SetFont('helvetica','B',18);
    $this->SetTextColor(255,255,255);
    $this->SetXY(10,5);
    $this->Cell(100,15,"My Title",0,0,'R');


}

// Page footer
function Footer()
{
    $this->SetY(-10);
    $this->SetFont('helvetica','I',7);

    $this->SetXY(100,-22);
    $this->Cell(100,15,'My Footer',0,0,'L');



}
}
```

Then instead of using a

```
$pdf = new FPDF();
```

You should use

```
$pdf = new PDF();
```

This way the same header and footer will be applied to all of your pages

Answer (score 0):

The way that you are expected to do this, at least from the comments in FPDF, is to inherit from the base `FPDF` class and implement the [`Header`](https://github.com/coreydoughty/Fpdf/blob/2ce0beb0002f074d2ef3020b049c50fff0be1f9a/src/Fpdf/Fpdf.php#L344) method:

```
use Fpdf\Fpdf;

class MyPdf extends Fpdf {
    function Header() {
        $this->Cell(100, 100, 'TITLE');
    }
}

$pdf = new MyPdf();
```

Additionally, there is a [`Footer`](https://github.com/coreydoughty/Fpdf/blob/2ce0beb0002f074d2ef3020b049c50fff0be1f9a/src/Fpdf/Fpdf.php#L348) method, which can be overridden in the same fashion if you need to have a footer on each page.